# Printing Store Database Design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I'm going to build an online printing store system which can be accessed by both the public (to order) and admin (process order).

This store I'm developing for has a lot of typical advertising products such as banners, name cards, rubber-stamp etc. And under these categories, there are several types of different items (based on different materials, finishing, size, quantity).

Admin can add new category, materials, types, and everything else that is required to create a new product.

To input a particular product price, will require all the details (ex: Banner, using material synthetic paper, size 2'x2', 100pcs, finishing extra 4 rings).

However, I'm stuck at trying to connect the other attributes since not every item will have the same attributes. And how to tabulate the drop-down menu for customer's order form and admin's management form (for the purpose of add, delete, edit)?

Update:
My current design of the database. Please correct me if there's a better solution.

Thanks!

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx4Xm.png)

Comment: You're refering to `Type` table which in fact on "ERD" is called `CategoryMaterial`. Please adjust your question to keep it consistent.

Comment: I'm always wondering why people reinvent the wheel. There is like a million solutions for online stores that you can deploy in minutes. You just customize the UI and fill the database. And then go spend time with your kids :)